# Javascript Show/Hide Play/Pause Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a Play and Pause button and I want the Play to turn into a Pause button when I click on it. I have my Play and Pause buttons ready in my CSS and my javascript in the head of my html.

However, when I click on the Play button, the Pause one won't display.

---

```js
<script>
$('#play').on('click', function(event) {
    currentPlayingTrack.play();

    $('#pause').show();
    $('#play').hide();
});

$('#pause').on('click', function(event) {
    currentPlayingTrack.pause();
    $('#pause').hide();
    $('#play').show();
});
</script>
```

```css
#play, #pause {
   width:80px;
   height: 80px;
   background: transparent;
   position: relative;
   margin-top: 10px;
   display: block;
}

#play {
    width: 0;        
    height: 0;
    border-left: 30px solid white;
    border-right: 30px solid transparent;
    border-top: 30px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 30px solid transparent; 
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 10px;
    left: 25px;
}

#pause:before {
    width: 10px;        
    height: 60px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 10px;
    left: 25px;
}

#pause:after {
    width: 10px;        
    height: 60px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 10px;
    right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<a href="#" id="play"></a> 
<a href="#" id="pause" style="display: none;"></a>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Does the play link hide correctly?

Comment: Its working, the only error I am finding is the `currentPlayingTrack is not defined`. Fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/flyinggambit/qju6rjps/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that your javascript is in the head of your html, but that means that it will be loaded and run before your buttons are added to the DOM, i.e., they will not be available to add a listener to.  [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j3pydev/cojfttoy/) with the script after your buttons and it runs fine.  For example:

```
<div>
    <a href="#" id="play"></a> 
    <a href="#" id="pause" style="display: none;"></a>
</div>
<script>
    $('#play').on('click', function(event) {
      //currentPlayingTrack.play();

      $('#pause').show();
      $('#play').hide();
    });

    $('#pause').on('click', function(event) {
      //currentPlayingTrack.pause();
      $('#pause').hide();
      $('#play').show();
    });
</script>
```

If you move the script before the buttons then the click listeners fire too early.  Scripts are run immediately upon loading.

Comment: Thanks! That works. Gotta place it at the center of the page now, as it just stays on the left side for the moment. 
Plus I have to make it bigger.

Comment: @mattvent Glad to hear it!  If you could mark this as the answer that'd be great :)

Comment: Just did it ;) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('#play').show();
});

$('#play').on('click', function(event) {
   //currentPlayingTrack.play();
    $('#pause').show();
    $('#play').hide();
});

$('#pause').on('click', function(event) {
    //currentPlayingTrack.pause();
    $('#pause').hide();
    $('#play').show();
});
```

```css
#play, #pause {
   width:80px;
   height: 80px;
   background: transparent;
   position: relative;
   margin-top: 10px;
   display: block;
}

#play {
    width: 0;        
    height: 0;
    border-left: 30px solid white;
    border-right: 30px solid transparent;
    border-top: 30px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 30px solid transparent; 
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 10px;
    left: 25px;
}

#pause:before {
    width: 10px;        
    height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 10px;
    left: 25px;
}

#pause:after {
    width: 10px;        
    height: 60px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 10px;
    right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<a href="#" id="play">Play</a> 
<a href="#" id="pause" style="display: none;">Pause</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. I have commented the `currentPlayingTrack.play();` for testing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#play').on('click', function (event) {
                //currentPlayingTrack.play();

                $('#pause').show();
                $('#play').hide();
            });

            $('#pause').on('click', function (event) {
                //currentPlayingTrack.pause();
                $('#pause').hide();
                $('#play').show();
            });
        })
    </script>
    <style>
        #play,
        #pause {
            width: 80px;
            height: 80px;
            background: transparent;
            position: relative;
            margin-top: 10px;
            display: block;
        }
        
        #play {
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-left: 30px solid white;
            border-right: 30px solid transparent;
            border-top: 30px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
            position: absolute;
            content: "";
            top: 10px;
            left: 25px;
        }
        
        #pause:before {
            width: 10px;
            height: 60px;
            background: white;
            position: absolute;
            content: "";
            top: 10px;
            left: 25px;
        }
        
        #pause:after {
            width: 10px;
            height: 60px;
            background: white;
            position: absolute;
            content: "";
            top: 10px;
            right: 25px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div>
        <a href="#" id="play">Play</a>
        <a href="#" id="pause" style="display: none;">Pause</a>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```